# Git Bash: no man command

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, git-bash

In Git Bash, I get an error for the `man` command:

```
$ man git
bash: man: command not found
```

My version of Git:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.18.0.windows.1
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Please also note that, even whether "a picture is worth one thousand words", it is preferable to post text and code as text (using the copy-paste feature of your OS) and not as an image containing text.

Comment: `man` command is not available on Windows even if you're using Git Bash.

Comment: It is possible to get `man` working in git-bash-for-Windows, but it's surprisingly non-trivial: https://superuser.com/questions/295398/man-pages-for-git-bash-on-windows-7

Comment: There is a file, explaining where to find the manpages: `/etc/manpath.config`.

Answer (score 16):

The [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org) package (aka Git Bash) does not include the Unix `man` command but you don't need it.

You can get help for any Git command by running [`git help <command-name>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help) (for example, `git help checkout`).

Also, you can read the help online at https://git-scm.com/docs.

Comment: This always opens the manual page to the browser, but I would like to see the man page in my terminal. Is there any way to use commands like `git help -m fetch` in Windows 11?

Answer (score 9):

On git bash you can use
**Command-name --help** insted of the **man command-name**

Comment: Not every command supports `--help` though. Git Bash-for-Windows does a lot more than just give you `git`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit overdue, but for anyone else using GitBash encountering this error, you'll have to use --help instead of man.

Example: `ls --help` instead of `man ls`

You can even use `git --help` to learn more about the git commands.

So pretty much if you want to find out more about a command, use (command name) --help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`pacman -S man` will certainly install the utility (as mentioned by @Alpha_B), but you do not require **Msys** for that. It can be simply installed using the command in git bash (administrator mode).

Answer (score 0):

"**git help**" does not work on my git bash but "**--help**" works, even though it shows more than necessary it's worth using.

Answer (score -1):

man, is one of the utilities available on Linux as part of the gnu project, and although git does give you the ability to install standard *nix tools like less, vim ...etc, it, for some reason, omits man, however you can install **Msys**, which comes with a package manager (pacman), which allows you to install man, and a lot more!
type a simple:
`pacman -S man`
(be sure you are running the terminal as admin)
you're gonna need to add the bin folders: "installDir/msys/bin", and "installDir/msys/usr/bin" to your path, so that you can access the tools from every terminal on your system.

Comment: This question is about Git on Windows.