# How to add the man command to git bash on windows and include the manuals

Tags: windows, git-bash

The popular man package on Linux seemingly comes as two components, a binary and a database. The binary is the code that executes man commands and the database contains the manual pages for the man command to serve.

With a fairly basic install of Windows 10 and [Git Bash for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) how can I install the man binary and the manual pages for the Git Bash commands which [appear to be here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/tree/master/mingw64/bin).

The goal being the ability to run `man curl`, `man bash` or `man git` and things Just Work.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [Git: man command don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51262422/7758804)